# Securing PHP web service calls

Tags: php, apache, security

I'm developing a web site which calls .PHP scripts to inject data into a MySQL database.

Because there is no security on these .PHP scripts, anyone in the world could run them over the web if they knew the proper parameter names and inject data into our database.

I know very little about security so I'm looking for a solution to secure these "web services".

I've read that using SSL may be the way to go but I'm not sure.

If anyone could make a recommendation and point me to a tutorial or website on how to implement this I would be greatly appreciative.

We are using Apache web server by the way if that matters.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you mean with 'no security' - beware of SQL injections (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). SSL is just a way to secure the transfer from client to server, but it doesn't affect the data you write to the database. There's a whole lot more to take care of, but you need to be way more specific about what exactly you want to 'secure' (and maybe show some code).

Comment: Do you need to invoke such scripts through an http connection in first place? If not my suggestion is to take a look (and use) PHP CLI instead. That's a much more secure approach.

Answer (score 2):

SSL will not solve the problem by itself. If someone can hit `http://yoursite.com/service.php`, they can also hit `https://yoursite.com/service.php`. SSL simple ensures that the actual data going over the wire is encrypted. But an encrypted injection request will have the same effect as a standard unencrypted one - you'll still have data injected into the database.

What you need is a password system of some sort. A bare bones minimal system would require a secret word to be sent along with each request, and any request without that word gets rejected/ignored. however, then you have to keep this secret word secret, and nothing on the web stays secret for very long.

Next up is assigning a specific key to each authorized user of your service. Nothing would prevent the users from sharing their key with others, but then you've got a per-user key that you can track down and beat up the person who DID share their key.

Past that, you can use HTTP level authentication, coupled with per-user access keys, which should prevent casual poking at the API. Without the http-level password, the API script is not even invoked, and even when it is, the proper API key must be present as well.

Comment: You can use this to implement basic http authentication: http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php

Comment: If you require a client to have a certificate to use SSL to connect to your .PHP web services, isn't that considered secure?